# How to output "Find" result or cell location in array or searchable area in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, list

I'm hoping someone has an idea of how I can list the cell location of a `COLOR#` in my example with a function instead of using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the cells that have the value I'm searching for and then typing in the locations where that value shows up in my array or "Green Area" in my example.

It would be nice if the output would show if there are multiple locations as shown on G22 but it's not essential. I looked at `=Address()` and `=MATCH` but they did't seem to give me the cell loation; only a `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is your dataset large?  This will require multiple IFERROR(MATCH) formulas nested inside one another or an array formula.  Neither is ideal when working with large datasets.

Comment: There might be a much easier way to do this. What problem are you trying to solve? Or, after finding in G22 that "7708-58" is in A3 and D7, what happens next? Where or how does that info get used?

Comment: The dataset will be about 500 entries or cells. The application is to setup a  location map of where sample chips cab be located on a grid sample board made up of about 500 samples 10x50 for a showroom

Comment: To simplify things perhaps lets assume there will be no duplicate values needed to be listed. There will only be one location listed for each "COLOR#". Again I appreciate any and all suggestions. Thanks

Comment: G2 is B2 because it matches "string" to "string" and you've used "conditinal formatting" I assume? If you are not using conditional formatting, then maybe it would solve some issues, especially if you don't know what conditional formatting is.

Comment: A second comment. Is it necessary for your colors (codes A1:D9) to be in this block? You would be better off aligning your codes in one single column (e.g. all color codes in one single file column, in ascending/alphabetical order). That way you could use a lookup which could also solve another problem. Using that and also Conditional Formatting could be what you are looking for. ? . ?

Comment: Unfortunately my dataset or (A1:D9) is a small representation of what my actual sample board looks like in my showroom. Each cell represents a sample chip on a peg board the customer can take with them. I wanted to make a "chip locator" or map so customers can look up a color by # and look it up on a grid.  I could manually  search each color and input the cell location but there are going to be over 500 colors and the company updates new colors every year.

Comment: So someone would come to you and ask you, "Where is 9927-GH?" And then you would look at your column? Control+F would be much faster because looking up a particular number takes time to read and even if you had the location you'd still have to look for it. Do you know how to use Access? A query would be great for this idea. You would start with a "database" then use a pop-up query where you'd manually enter the code, and then the query-result would be a subset of data with it's location entered at an earlier date. I do have another idea if you  are not familiar with Access. An ordered droplist

Comment: I have a solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data set is a small sample. I will show you with a subset of your data how to use Conditional Formatting. This should enable you to "dynamically search" for a number and "gauge" where it is at at any time.

**Step 1**: Select all "Searchable Data". Via your example, that would be selecting `A1:D9`.

**Step 2**: Home Tab; select Conditional Formatting. Then select `Highlight Cell Rules`. Then select `Equal To`.

**Step 3**: In the image I've provided, the `searching criteria` is entered manually. This search criteria is set in a predetermined cell; `F2`. The search is performed here.

**Final Step**: If the criteria exists in the data-set, then the cells will highlight; all the other cells will remain uncolored.

[image]

And another search: **299-58**

[image]

Since the OP gained some insight on this solution, gained awareness of Excel's possibilities, I've decided to add some breadth for even more knowledge awesomeness.

---

**EXTRA** - to further the demonstrate capabilities of automation.

---

ADD a **SEARCH** and **Combo-Box** (Drop-List) to cut down on data-entry errors.

An image should suffice for a thousand words or so.
[image]

No **Developer's Tab**?
[image]

Comment: This  is  actually better then what I originally had in mind! Thank you for your effort. This definitively solves my problem and actually gives me more options in the future for searching this massive sample board. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Jared Hey, glad I could help. Getting to know Excel is uphill all the way. Stick with it and you'll be an expert in no time. Please check the box next to the solution to let onlookers know it's been solved.

Comment: @Jared Furthermore you could have a list of all possible codes on another sheet. Then you could have a drop-down list inserted above the search-cell. When the drop-list is selected the search-cell will populate with your selection and the same Conditional formatting will happen. I like to use drop-lists because it keeps the data "error free" or at least tries to. I'll add it to my solution so maybe it can help you or someone else out. It's an easy step and after a few times you'll know how to execute it any time (it uses a `lookup` in `ASC` order too).

Comment: @Jared I added a quick reference, in how to add a `ComboBox` as a search List (all possible codes) and reference the result as search criteria in a `vlookup` formula to the same cell; but instead of manually entering a code it's now a list to choose from.

Comment: This is truly exceptional!.Very informative and easy to follow. I'm doing some research now to see if I can throw all this on a Raspberry pi and have a dedicated system for people to easily look up sample locations. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jared Glad to help out!